# Executing shell script over website: Always run in one single instance

Tags: php, html, bash, shell

I'm calling a bash script over a website using html/php. There are multiple html-buttons available that always start the same script, but with different arguments.
The problem is, that every time I start to call the script by clicking on such a button, a new instance of the script is opened.

Is it possible to kind of *"pick up" the running instance of the script* and not starting a new one?

**Note:** i can't just exit the active instance of the script and starting a new one, as serveral background functions are running which would be stopped then too.

Comment: What's the issue with starting a new instance?

Comment: @thiru About every 2 minutes one of the buttons gets clicked, so this would mean one new instance every 2 minutes -> loosing control, needs lots of cpu (running on a Raspberry Pi), ...

Comment: Alright. It's not possible to "pick up" a running instance. Instead, you can modify your script to make it a background process (which will always be running) and send the arguments to it through a pipe.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @thiru for the hint!
I used the [instruction from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31417284/bash-pipe-output-into-background-process) using mkfifo to create a pipe and then just echoing arguments into the pipe.